# cache within getters/setters?

Tags: caching, typescript

If I have a getter like this:

```
export class foo{
    aaa: number;
    bbb: number;
    ccc: number;

    constructor(){
        //whatever
    }

    get getHeight(f: number){
        return (f + 16) * Math.ceil(Math.round(Math.tan(aaa) + bbb/2) * ccc);
    }
}
```

where `aaa`, `bbb`, and `ccc` is a constant that does not get changed during runtime.

I have to call the getter multiple times from other classes during runtime, so I want to be able to reduce performance as much as possible by "cache"ing `Math.ceil(Math.round(Math.tan(aaa) + bbb/2) * ccc)`. Is it possible to do this without having to make a completely new variable inside the `foo` class?

*bonus question: Is it possible in typescript to combine same variable types into one? like in java, I can do something like:

```
int aaa, bbb, ccc;
```

but it seems like typescript doesnt allow that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this without having to make a completely new variable inside the foo class

nope. TypeScript doesn't have *static function local variables* which is effectively what you are asking for.

> Is it possible in typescript to combine same variable types into one? like in java, I can do something like

Not a part of the standard way in TypeScript + I don't have a clever trick here.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should export this calculation to an external static class that does this calculation one time on the class definition like this:

```
class Calculator {
    static a : number = 5;
    static b : number = 6;
    static c : number = 7;
    static height : number = Math.ceil(Math.round(Math.tan(Calculator.a) + Calculator.b/2) * Calculator.c);
}

export class foo{

    constructor(){
        //whatever
    }

    getHeight(f: number){
        return (f + 16) * Calculator.height;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you trying to do. But how is that? [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=export%20class%20foo%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F*%20Is%20not%20visible%20outside%20of%20foo.%20*%2F%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20factor%20%3D%20Math.ceil%28Math.round%28Math.tan%28foo.aaa%29%20%2B%20foo.bbb%2F2%29%20*%20foo.ccc%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20constructor%28%29%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fwhatever%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getHeight%28f%3A%20number%29%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%28f%20%2B%2016%29%20*%20foo.factor%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20module%20foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F*%20Use%20module%20mixing%20for%20constant%20variables%2C%20*%2F%0A%20%20%20%20export%20const%20aaa%20%3D%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20export%20const%20bbb%20%3D%202%3B%0A%20%20%20%20export%20const%20ccc%20%3D%203%3B%0A%7D)

```
export class foo{
    /* Is not visible outside of foo. */
    private static factor = Math.ceil(Math.round(Math.tan(foo.aaa) + foo.bbb/2) * foo.ccc);

    public constructor(){
        //whatever
    }

    public getHeight(f: number){
        return (f + 16) * foo.factor;
    }
}

export module foo {
    /* Use module mixing for constant variables, */
    export const aaa = 1;
    export const bbb = 2;
    export const ccc = 3;
}
```

Or like this? [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=export%20class%20foo%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F*%20or%20readonly%20propierties.%20*%2F%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20aaa%28%29%7B%20return%201%3B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20bbb%28%29%7B%20return%202%3B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20ccc%28%29%7B%20return%203%3B%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F*%20Is%20still%20not%20visible%20outside%20of%20foo.%20*%2F%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20factor%20%3D%20Math.ceil%28Math.round%28Math.tan%28foo.aaa%29%20%2B%20foo.bbb%2F2%29%20*%20foo.ccc%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20constructor%28%29%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fwhatever%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getHeight%28f%3A%20number%29%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%28f%20%2B%2016%29%20*%20foo2.factor%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

```
export class foo{

    /* or readonly propierties. */
    public get aaa(){ return 1;};
    public get bbb(){ return 2;};
    public get ccc(){ return 3;};

    /* Is still not visible outside of foo. */
    private static factor = Math.ceil(Math.round(Math.tan(foo.aaa) + foo.bbb/2) * foo.ccc);

    public constructor(){
        //whatever
    }

    public getHeight(f: number){
        return (f + 16) * foo2.factor;
    }
}
```